# Vi keys in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, plugins, vi

I'm surprised no one has asked this yet. What's the best way (if any) to get a Vi experience in Xcode? I know about ViMate but TextMate doesn't come close to Xcode in terms of integration and code completion.

BTW, I am using Xcode 4.

Comment: You can file a radar with Apple asking for Vi keybindings in Xcode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vim key bindings in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011758/vim-key-bindings-in-xcode)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might want to try out [xVim](https://github.com/WarWithinMe/xVim) which seems to be an active project.  The currently indicate that it works with XCode 4.2, Espresso and Chocolat.  Presumably you could selectively enable it with other applications.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't believe the moment when I saw it actually work! Though it is still severely primitive feature-wise, at least it works.

Comment: I've tested xVim with XCode 4.5, and it works well; not only that, but the plug-in seems to be in active development!

Answer (score 6):

Here's another plugin which I made a few weeks ago.
http://programming.jugglershu.net/softwares/xvim.html

This is currently developed for personal (my) use. So you may feel bad with some lack of implementation. Give me a feed back(feature request) then. I'll add some keybinds if I have enough time.

Comment: Originally I thought this was the same plugin as mentioned in @JamesSynder 's answer. But actually this is another plugin with the same name. Your version works very great and I personally prefer it over the other xVim version. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The closest you'll get is http://www.corsofamily.net/jcorso/vi/, or configuring an external editor. This has been a long-standing deficiency with XCode. (If you ask any vi user that is..)

OSX and XCode in general favors Emacs key bindings.

More info on general key-binding strategy for OSX: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060317045211408

Comment: I could never get it to work, so I assumed it's broken (since it hasn't been updated for some time). Just to get some encouragement, can you get it to work with OS X 10.6 and Xcode 4?

Comment: I haven't tried in a while.. Lucky for you I have a long build going. I'll give it a stab right now.

Comment: I spoke too soon - Input managers are 'somewhat' depricated. i.e. you can use them, but only if the app is in 32-bit mode. XCode still ships with a 32bit universal binary, so it's not out of the question. But, honestly even when the Vi Input Manager worked it's best, it still wasn't that great.. Another link for another poor man's solution: http://weblog.highorderbit.com/post/3901744683/learning-to-leave-vim-and-embrace-xcode .. I'll keep digging though. I'm curious now.

Comment: Looks like MacVim has some integration with XCode, it's still not as nice as having everything in one place, but.. it's something. http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/vim-mac/message/5671 I think that's as good as it'll get.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, I productively use [XVim](https://github.com/JugglerShu/XVim/tree/refactoring)†. I'll probably try $20 [ViCiOUS](http://viciousapp.com), which seems more polished; I like having source access to my tool-chain, but this is for Xcode, so *c'mon* me.

† **Not** [xVim](https://github.com/WarWithinMe/xVim), which I just discovered, but apparently face down in the pool. In the [Xx][Vv]im namespace, Xvim (à la Xcode) would have made more sense to me. There, I said it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another choice: [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/).